# Why won't Linux let me play with /dev/dsp?

Tags: linux-mint, devices

I'm working through a Linux textbook, and it's telling me about devices.  It says that if I send the appropriate output to `/dev/dsp`, then it will play a sound.  The example is `cat file.wav > /dev/dsp`, where file.wav is just any .wav file.

When I do this I get permission denied.  If I run this with sudo I still get permission denied.  If I `su` first, no sound plays.

Why do I get permission denied with `sudo`?  Why does no sound play even with `su`?

Comment: Make sure your user is in the `audio` group.

Comment: You might also need to ensure that your wav file is raw audio - not all .wav files are raw.

Comment: @DrakeClarris, that would cause noise to be output, not a permission denied error.

Comment: @cjm I was thinking more of the silence when playing using su

Answer (score 22):

`/dev/dsp` is part of OSS, which hasn't been part of the Linux kernel in... a very long time. It has long been supplanted by ALSA, which uses different devices, different programs, and a different API.

There is an emulation layer module though. If it is available then loading the `snd-pcm-oss` module will enable you to use the PCM devices for OSS such as `/dev/dsp`.

Or just stick to piping data to `aplay` or `paplay` instead.

Comment: `sudo modprobe snd-pcm-oss` works on my ubuntu to load that module. I get a `/dev/dsp1` and a `/dev/dsp2` out of this.

Comment: How do you load the `snd-pcm-oss` module? On Ubuntu 18.04, when I run `sudo modprobe snd-pcm-oss`, I get error: `modprobe: FATAL: Module snd-pcm-oss not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-169-generic`

Answer (score 14):

> If I run this with sudo I still get permission denied.

By this statement, it sounds like you are trying a command like:

```
sudo cat file.wav > /dev/dsp
```

The reason you continue to get "permission denied" is that your shell *first* tries to open the `/dev/dsp` device for output, *before* running the command (which is `sudo`). To have the shell open the redirection with root privileges, you would have to do something like:

```
sudo sh -c 'cat file.wav > /dev/dsp'
```

Answer (score 10):

Out of date book, as noted.

So to make the examples work with more modern linux, where it says something like

```bsh
cat music.wav > /dev/dsp
```

change it to:

```bsh
cat music.wav | aplay
# or
aplay music.wav
```

Comment: Examples you can test on Ubuntu 18.04+, for example: `cat /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav | aplay` or `aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav`

Comment: Doesn't work for all audio format output.  Piping sidplay2 to `paplay` results in `Failed to open audio file.`.  Piping to `aplay` results in `aplay: read_header:2834: read error`.